# Is there WIFI Permission in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, wifi

I was trying to solve this issue for several weeks. I created a system for auditing asset using a handheld scanner. We are using this system for more than 1yr and I didn't encounter issues in our location in terms in a handheld. Then we implemented this system in other location but the server is the same. After they set up the wifi handheld and already connected to the server, we encounter a problem. All insert and update are not reflecting into the database. They can log-in and query asset. When I try to test on the PC, it runs normally. NOTE: PC in windows based authentication and the handheld is native account and connection wifi connection of the PC and Handheld is not same. So I conclude that there may be some permission needed in handheld wifi(I don't have any background in networking so this only my guess). Is my conclusion is correct? or what is the possible problem?

Comment: Are your handheld devices capable of debugging of any sort? Can you see what the error is that's occurring? If not, I'd set up some logging on the database. Either in the procedure being called (assuming a procedure is being called) or some sort of trigger on the database to monitor logins and/or DML on the table.

Comment: I use try catch and it did not throw any error. I already check the IIS log and their no error there.

Comment: Occam's Razor. I suspect it's the subnet or IP address range. Easiest way to put access restrictions on those than control it with anything else. That's one way I'd restrict access to my servers.

Comment: @I.R.R. Can you explain furtherly?

Comment: I would secure my database by having a bunch of access control restrictions. One of them would be to restrict access to say for example, IP addresses 10.1.20.2--127 for example. If I didn't match the wifi dhcp to serve addresses in that range, and just left the default on the wifi for my organization of 10.1.30.2-100, then I'd have a subnet mismatch. If I just left the wifi router at the default 192.168.1.2-100 then I'd have an IP mismatch. In either case, the firewall on my server  would block the connection.

Comment: @I.R.R. That was my first thought too, or that the wifi AP was in guest mode (no intranet access), but he said that *"They can log-in and query asset"*, which means that there is read connectivity.  He also said *"PC in windows based authentication and the handheld is native account"*, so they're not using the same credentials to log in.

Comment: A good sysadmin/network admin would secure it on both points so if it turns out it's just an ip address thing, make sure that authentication is also a thing. Edit: I just read his response to your answer. I think your answer is even simpler therfore more likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question, no, there's no Wifi or network-level permissions in SQL Server.  I'm guessing that the user(s) that the devices are using to log in do not have the correct permissions on the database.  Try using exactly the same credentials on the local PC as you are using on the handhelds, and I think you'll find you have the same problem.  If so, you need to either use Windows Auth on the handhelds (if that's even an option), or fix your native login's permissions.

Comment: I already check the native permission and all needed permission is given to the native account.

Comment: But did you test from the PC with those exact same login credentials?

Comment: Well, I use the same native credential in both locations so that means there is no problem in native account permission.

Comment: what do you mean by `native credentail` and how can you sure these `native credential` has the read & write access rights ?

Comment: and when you say "in both locations", are you talking about both physical locations, or did you actually try it on the PC in the new location?  If you've tried exactly the same credentials in a PC at the new location and that gives you write access then I have no idea what the issue is, but I'd be looking to add logging to the mobile application you have developed to see what happens when you try to do an insert or update.  It shouldn't ever fail silently (if it's written correctly), and there should be an error code or message you can investigate.  Good luck.